# Problem getting name of input of type file from html Tag

Tags: javascript, function, file, variables, input

```
vinsertBtn.onclick = function(){
  insertData();
} 
function insertData(){
  var vimages = document.getElementById("cfile");
  var thefile = vimages.files[0];   

  vfinishicon.style.display = 'none';

  // Create a root reference
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("productImages/"+thefile.name);
  var idxDot = thefile.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
  var extFile = thefile.namethefile.name.substr(idxDot, thefile.name.length).toLowerCase();

  if (extFile !== "jpg" && extFile !== "jpeg" && extFile!=="png"){
      $("#resultID").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
      $("#resultID").text("only jpeg or png are accepted.");
      vresult.focus();
      return;
  }
```

with this code a have this error:

> insertproduct.html:269 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined
>       at insertData (insertproduct.html:269)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.vinsertBtn.onclick (insertproduct.html:261)

Comment: Maybe removing `.namethefile` from `extFile` value helps?

Comment: `thefile.namethefile` <-- what is `namethefile`

Comment: thanks for this remark but this is not the real error.

Comment: The error message says that `thefile.namethefile` is undefined, what can be more real?